# Put two images with different height aligned to the top of the page LaTeX

Tags: latex

I would like to create landscape document with two-column pages.
On the left side of each page is located a bigger image (covering more less the left part of page and aligned to the top of the page), on the right side is located smaller image covering about 1/3 on the right side of the page, aligned to the top and with some description below

```tex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image-3x4}
    \captionof{figure}{Example picture proportion 3:4}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.01\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}{0.49\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image-3x1}
    \captionof{figure}{Example picture proportion 3:1}

    Some extra description on the right side
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Actual output:
[image]

Desired output:
[image]

How to create two images side-by-side aligned to the top of the page as desired?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `valign` key (needs the `adjutsbox` package):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}
    \captionof{figure}{Example picture proportion 3:4}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.01\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1cm,valign=t]{example-image-duck}
    \captionof{figure}{Example picture proportion 3:1}

    Some extra description on the right side
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: valign solved my issue, thanks

Comment: @SławomirSiudek You're welcome!